# Upstart script produces folder with question mark at the end. Why?

Tags: ubuntu, upstart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bash/Korn shell script edited on Windows throws error ‘…^M: not found’](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56024/bash-korn-shell-script-edited-on-windows-throws-error-m-not-found)

I'm writting an Upstart job to run Postgresql:

```
description "PostgreSQL 9.1 Server"
author "PostgreSQL"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]
respawn
pre-start script
    if [ -d /var/run/postgresql ]; then
        chmod 2775 /var/run/postgresql
    else
        install -d -m 2775 -o postgres -g postgres /var/run/postgresql
    fi
end script
exec su -c "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.1/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/postgresql.conf" postgres
```

If I run separate command directly from shell, they work fine. However, if they are run through Upstart... the folder gets named `/var/run/postgresql?`.

Note the question mark at the end. Why does it occur??

Comment: Any chance your file has wrong line-endings (Windows or Mac)?

Comment: I just solved my problem by hand typing the file on the server itself. I did not know it was such an issue uploading ascii files from windows to linux, now i do ;)

Comment: Here's a related question with the "usual" result of that  (i.e. command not found errors): http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56024/bash-korn-shell-script-edited-on-windows-throws-error-m-not-found Contains ways to fix it other than just re-typing the while thing :)

Comment: You means `ls` shows a `?`, right? That `?` actually stands for an unprintable character, to wit, a carriage return (CR, ^M). See [Bash/Korn shell script edited on Windows throws error '...^M: not found'](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/56024) for the rest of the story.