# Why does downloading bash script from pastebin not work?

Tags: shell-script, wget

I'm trying to upload and download a bash script from pastebin, upload was straightforward enough with copy and paste, download didn't go as easy.

There are two scripts I'm trying to download, these are the commands:

```
wget http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=M6iQ6RaY --output-document=ts3update
wget http://pastebin.com/raw/e11R2wkP --output-document=ts3restore
```

When I try to run them, I get  this error:

```
./ts3update: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Then if I remove the interpreter line, I just get this:

```
./ts3update: line 4: $'\r': command not found
```

And this:

```
./ts3restore: line 3: $'\r': command not found
./ts3restore: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `$'in\r''
'/ts3restore: line 7: `        case $yn in
```

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it? When I read or grep the files I find no instances of **^M** or **'\r'** why does bash see something like that when nothing else does?

Comment: Your downloaded file has Windows CRLF line endings (^M is carriage return). Use `dos2unix ts3restore`.

Comment: @MichaelHomer not really a duplicate, while the solution may be the same, the issue is different; e.g. if this gets deleted because of that, other users may just repeat my question. Anyhow, the best answer was in there (the sed one), i'll go ahead and post it. Thanks.

Comment: no, really, it is a duplicate.  It doesn't matter how the script got windows CRLF line-endings (there is an enormous number of ways that could happen, and it would be absurd to treat them all as completely different problems rather than as minor/irrelevant variations of the same problem), the fact is that it has them, and the problem is the same - `/bin/bash^M` does not exist, so can not be used as an interpreter to run the script.  The solution is also the same - convert to unix style LF-only line-endings.

Comment: @cas Hmm I guess so.

Answer (score 1):

The answer as Michael Homer pointed out is that pastebin has added Windows CRLF line endings to my files. To fix it I ran the following:

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' ts3update
sed -i 's/\r$//' ts3restore
```

And the scripts executed successfully. The answer was taken from here: [Bash/Korn shell script edited on Windows throws error '...^M: not found'](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56024/bash-korn-shell-script-edited-on-windows-throws-error-m-not-found)